Eigenvalues of $A-A^T$
I wonder what can we say about the eigenvalues of the the matrix $A-A^T$, where $A$ is a real matrix. We know that $A$ and $A^T$ share the same eigenvalues. If $A$ is symmetric, the solution is trivial. Similarly if $A$ and $A^T$ commute. But what is happening in general? Is there any relation with the eigenvalues of $A$?

If $A=\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$ then $A-A^t$ has eigenvalues $\pm(b-c)i$, so I'd say there's no relation to the eigenvalues of $A$.

Fun fact: if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ odd, then $0$ must be an eigenvalue of $A - A^T$

There is no precise relationship between the eigenvalues of $A-A^T$ and those of $A$. However, we may observe the following:

The eigenvalues are either zero or pure imaginary. If you multiply $A-A^T$ by $i=\sqrt{-1}$ the result is a Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues are real.

Add the absolute values of all nondiagonal elements of $A$ in row $k$ and in column $k$. The maximum of this sum for all $k$ is $\ge$ the $L_1$ norm of $A-A^T$ and thus bounds the magnitudes of all the imaginary eigenvalues. For instance, if $A$ is a 3×3 matrix with $A_{ij}=1$ for $i>j$, $A_{ij}=0$ elsewhere, then the sum given here is $1+1=2$ for each $k$ and the eigenvalues of $A-A^T$ end up as $0,\pm i\sqrt3$.



I see that from the Gersgorin theorem, the spectral radius of $A$ does not exceed your sum, by why the same holds for the spectral radius of $A-A^T$?

I am applying the Gershgorin theorem to $A-A^T$, combined with the triangle inequality that results when the columns of $A$ are matched to the corresponding rows of $A^T$.

I see now. I have misunderstood that you are dealing with the column and the row simultaneously.

$A-A^T$ is skew-symmetric, hence its trace is zero. This implies that the sum of its eigenvalues is zero.
